# how to use INDEX and MATCH in this condition in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have sheet with data, want to use index and match formula to get data in other sheet. But their is a condition  and i dont know how to add this rule in formula to got value what i want. 
i tried this formula `=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(D1,Sheet1!A:A,0))`

want to copy values from sheet1 column A to other sheet but higher ones. imean i have two or three values for same product. but want to copy only if value more then 100 .

Here is sample sheet1 data :

```
|--------------------------------------------------------|
| Cell A                     | Cell B                    |                   
|--------------------------------------------------------|
| 60                         | tgh                       |                   
|--------------------------------------------------------|
| 400                        | hou                       |                   
|--------------------------------------------------------|
| 900                        | hop                       |                   
|--------------------------------------------------------|
| 80                         | hop                       |                   
|--------------------------------------------------------|
| 200                        | tgh                       |                   
|--------------------------------------------------------|
| 200                        | tgh                       |                   
|--------------------------------------------------------|
```

what i want, sheet2 example :

```
|--------------------------------------------------------|
| Cell C                     | Cell D                    |                  
|--------------------------------------------------------|
| 400                        | hou                       |                   
|--------------------------------------------------------|
| 900                        | hop                       |                   
|--------------------------------------------------------|
| 200                        | tgh                       |                   
|--------------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: It seems to be a typical job for a pivot table, why do you want to do it with formulas?

Comment: @MátéJuhász because this sheet have more data that i cant  go with pivot table . refine all data with many formulas , here on this step i stuck . so need help with formula .. thanks

Comment: The bigger issue isn't how to use index and match to get numbers in Column C, but collect all the text (as many as necessary of them) in Column D

Comment: @MátéJuhász Column D already has values. I want to index and match column D cell value with column B cell and if the value in equivalent column A cell is higher than 100, it should get printed in column C cell. hope you understand ..

Comment: see if this helps :https://exceljet.net/formula/position-of-max-value-in-list